# Specify default analyzer in NEST or Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-5

How can I specify default analyzer in NEST? Or alternative in Elasticsearch?  I want change standard analyzer to language analyzer!

Comment: Take a look at the documentation on writing analyzers: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-analyzers.html#_creating_a_custom_analyzer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using automap in nest you can use an attribute like so

```cs
 public class A
        {
            [Text(Analyzer = "NameOfTheAnalyzer")]
            public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        }
```

If you want the *default* mapping you can set it like so

```cs
var request = new CreateIndexRequest(indexName)
        {
            Mappings = new Mappings()
            {
                ["_default_"] = new TypeMapping()
                {
                    Properties = new Properties
                    {
                        ["id"] = new KeywordProperty { Index = false },
                        ["title"] = new TextProperty { Analyzer = "NameOfTheAnalyzer" }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
 var create = client.CreateIndex(request);
```